# Stream iterator reading std::cin misses 2nd and 3rd numbers

Tags: c++, vector, cin, istream-iterator

```
std::vector<int> v{};
std::istream_iterator<int> iter(std::cin), eof;

while (iter != eof) {
  v.push_back(*iter);
  ++iter;
}
```

When it executes, this program ignores the second and third integers entered into the standard input. For example, entering `1 2 3 4 5 ^Z` and hitting enter results in a vector containing `1 4 5`. The same thing happens when the input is separated by newline characters instead of spaces.

It's a simple example taken from C++ Primer (5th ed, p403) so I assume the fault lies with me. I've been stuck on this for a few hours so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: The code I originally posted was incomplete.** `iter2(std::cin)` and `iter3(std::cin)` were also in the program and I thought they were only declarations at this point but it turns out they were responsible for the missing input. Code should have looked like:

```
std::vector<int> v{};
std::istream_iterator<int> iter(std::cin), iter2(std::cin), iter3(std::cin), eof;

while (iter != eof) {
  v.push_back(*iter);
  ++iter;
}
```

Lesson learned and apologies. Is it customary to delete terrible questions like this?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, not me, but the question was unclear (showing wrong code that doesn't even compile, due to incorrect variable names). It still doesn't show a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely  Why the code does not compile?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35575687/revisions

Comment: @Sanders, works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92d48ebdf875775f) so you're not showing the problem.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Anyone can make a typo. It is not a reason for down-voting. It could be pointed out in a comment.

Comment: `typedef std::istream_iterator<int> int_it; std::copy(int_it(std::cin), int_it(), std::back_inserter(v));` can be done like so, without an explicit loop

Comment: @Sanders  You should show a complete compiled minimal program that demonstrates the problem. It is not clear why you concluded that the vector contains 1, 4, 5.

Comment: There were two lines I omitted where I tied 2 other iterators to std::cin. I didn't think they were relevant but lesson learned - always run the exact code you give. My apologies and thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I always wonder that a question has just appeared has no comments but it is already down-voted. It seems there are participants that all they do is downvoting questions and nothing else.:)

Answer (score 2):

Constructing more than one iterator *may* affect the result, as the iterator constructor is allowed to read ahead and buffer the next input.

The standard says [istream.iterator.cons]:

> `istream_iterator(istream_type& s);`
>
> Effects: Initializes *in_stream* with `&s`. *value* may be initialized during construction or the first time it is referenced.
>
> Postcondition: `in_stream == &s`.

Here, *in_stream* and *value* are "exposition only" member variables, used to show that an implementation might buffer the next input, possibly to optimize `operator*` or to check for end-of-file.

Comment: Thanks Bo, this answers the question I meant to ask rather than the one I initially did. Now I understand what's going on I did some debugging. The three iterators point to the first 3 numbers entered respectively, these numbers are removed from std::cin, and all 3 iterators will increment to point to '4' which is the next value in cin.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `*iter` and not `*iterator` when you dereference it

```
    int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{};
    std::istream_iterator<int> iter(std::cin), eof;

    while (iter != eof) {
        v.push_back(*iter);
        ++iter;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        cout << v[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Always pays to use some meaningful names for variables

Comment: and ++iter to incremeny it

Comment: Crap, I just changed the name half way through writing the question  but it's not that. Good catch though.

Comment: @Sanders I've edited my answer above to post the whole snippet of working code